# Inject Popper.js in Chrome Extension Content script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

This is my flow: Content script -> Fetch data using background.js -> Return data and inject the new HTML into the webpage.

Now I have to show a tooltip using Popper.js but I get the error "document" is undefined.
It's strange because I am in content-scripts.js. How can I get the newly updated dom after my injection?

**content-scripts.js**

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({command: "sales_data", data: payload}, function(items) {
   let view = new SearchResultsView(items)
   view.injectToDom()
        
   const popcorn = document.querySelector('#popcorn'); // document is undefined
   const tooltip = document.querySelector('#tooltip'); // document is undefined
   createPopper(popcorn, tooltip, {
      placement: 'top',
   });

});
```

SearchResultsView/InjectDom()

```
   let html = `<div id="popcorn" aria-describedby="tooltip"></div>
                        <div id="tooltip" role="tooltip">
                        My tooltip
                        <div id="arrow" data-popper-arrow></div>
                        </div>`
    //...
    element.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', html);
```

Comment: It's important to show how your code is declared/injected because name alone doesn't mean anything. The exact error text is also important because usually it's not the document is undefined but the element i.e. the result of querySelector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED.

I had to import tippy.js.

```
import { createPopper } from '@popperjs/core';
import tippy from 'tippy.js';


tippy('#button', {
   content: 'My tooltip!',
});
```

Comment: I'm currently trying to do something similar. Did you import tippy into your background.js? From what I understand, you cannot import into the content.js file. Additionally, how did you import the libraries? Locally for via CDN?